# Convergence criteria for interior

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

My book gives three equivalent statements as a theorem, under the heading "Convergence criteria for interior" :

Suppose X is a metric space, z is in X and S is a non empty subset of X.

First,z is in int(S)

Second, S includes a tail of every sequence in X that converges to z in X.

Third, no sequence in S complement converges to z in X.

I can see that, these three statements are equivalent but i can't follow what this theorem is actually trying to convey ?

What does "Convergence criteria for interior" mean ?

Comment: Criteria for points to be interior points of $S$ in terms of convergence of sequences. ($z$ is an interior point of $S$ if and only if ... some criteria for sequences converging to $z$). Terrible formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the heading is poorly worded: it made me think that interiors of some sets converge to some other set. *Sequential characterization of interior points* would be a better name, similar to well-known sequential characterizations of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ and of "$f$ is continuous at $a$".

Anyway, all the book wanted to do was to give two properties that are equivalent to $z$ being an interior point of $S$. How they are called is not particularly important; if you pick another book, you won't find the same name there.